# How to add configurable external JS with data- attributes in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs

I want to add external JavaScript library in my module.
It looks something like below script code

```
<script 
src="<?php echo $block->escapeUrl($block->getJsLibUrl());?>" 
data-min="<?php echo (int)$block->getMinLimit(); ?>"    
data-max="<?php echo (int)$block->getMaxLimit(); ?>" async>
</script>
```

Here, the script URL is dynamic and data min/max values too.

I am not sure how I can add this external js library with data attributes in Magento 2 standard way. Is it fine if I will add this script in **.phtml** file? or is there any alternate way to add using requireJS?

Thanks for your attention and help in advance. Feel free to ask if more details are needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you can do this way. Magento has done the similar things in number of places for example look at vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/templates/product/edit/tabs.phtml in your magento2 core folder. This is just one example, there are several others too. So, I think this isn't a bad practice if Magento is following it too.